# UIScrollView not able to scroll?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

I have this `UIScrollView` set up with a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`.
However, it's not scrolling like I want it to. It's like it's not even there... How can I fix this? I just want it to be scrollable (even though theres nothing at the bottom to scroll to yet)

Thx in advance!

Here's my code:

```
    // scrollView
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    // scrollView constraints
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

    // Initialize profileImageView
    profileImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "neil")
    profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 125 / 2
    profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    scrollView.addSubview(profileImageView)

    // Add profileImageView constraints
    profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 45).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 125).isActive = true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 125).isActive = true
    profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    // Add separator view
    seperator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    seperator.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    scrollView.addSubview(seperator)

    // seperator constraints
    seperator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2).isActive = true
    seperator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
    seperator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    seperator.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

    //nameLabel
    let nameLabelFont = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 36, weight: UIFont.Weight.heavy)
    nameLabel.font = nameLabelFont
    nameLabel.text = currentUser.name
    nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.addSubview(nameLabel)

    // nameLabel constraints
    nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: seperator.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: seperator.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't scroll because `scrollView.contentSize` isn't bigger then your view.

If you want make your screen scrollable you should set `scrollView.contentSize`.

Put `scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000)` before `view.addSubview(scrollView)` to set your scrollable area to 1000x1000.

Generally `scrollView.contentSize` should be calculated base on UI elements inside `UIScrollView` e.g. size of 10 images with space between them.

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a lot!